# Cant seem to figure out how to dynamically add points to a line graph using HoloGraphLibrary.

Tags: android

I have been doing research on how to implement Line graphs.  I really enjoy HoloGraphLibrary from, https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/wiki/Home.  Can someone help me implement or get me moving in the right direction to add points to a line graph. I was hoping to use database positions for X-Axis and entry data for the Y-Axis.

I dont know how to add **LinePoint p = new LinePoint();**.  Any suggestions will be helpful.

**HoloGraph XML**

```
<com.echo.holographlibrary.LineGraph
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/graph"/>
```

**HoloGraph**

```
    Line l = new Line();
    LinePoint p = new LinePoint();
    p.setX(0);
    p.setY(5);
    l.addPoint(p);
    p = new LinePoint();
    p.setX(8);
    p.setY(8);
    l.addPoint(p);
    p = new LinePoint();
    p.setX(10);
    p.setY(4);
    l.addPoint(p);
    l.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33"));

    LineGraph li = (LineGraph) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    li.addLine(l);
    li.setRangeY(0, 10);
    li.setLineToFill(0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LineGraph.addPointToLine(lineIndex,newPointX,newPointY);`

Here is a working example (See the Button's onClickListener)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

LineGraph mLineGraph;
EditText mEditText;
float lastX; // Last x coordinate

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources resources = getResources();

    Line line = new Line();
    line.setUsingDips(true);

    // Initialize graph with some points
    List<LinePoint> points = new ArrayList<LinePoint>(20);
    points.add(new LinePoint(0,0));
    points.add(new LinePoint(1,2));
    points.add(new LinePoint(2,10));
    points.add(new LinePoint(3,5));
    lastX = 3;
    for(LinePoint p : points) {
        line.addPoint(p);
    }

    line.setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.orange));
    mLineGraph = (LineGraph) findViewById(R.id.linegraph);
    mLineGraph.setUsingDips(true);
    mLineGraph.addLine(line);
    mLineGraph.setRangeY(0, 10);
    mLineGraph.setLineToFill(0);

    mLineGraph.setOnPointClickedListener(new LineGraph.OnPointClickedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int lineIndex, int pointIndex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Line " + lineIndex + " / Point " + pointIndex + " clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Add point after the last X coord with Y coord from EditText
            lastX++;
            float newY = Float.parseFloat(mEditText.getText().toString());
            mLineGraph.addPointToLine(0,lastX,newY);
        }
    });

}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Y coordinate"
        android:id="@+id/edittext"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add another point"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.echo.holographlibrary.LineGraph
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linegraph"
    app:lineStrokeColor="@color/transparent_orange"
    app:lineAxisColor="@color/transparent_blue"
    app:lineStrokeWidth="1dip"
    app:lineStrokeSpacing="10dip"
    app:lineUseDip="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**colors.xml** (Taken from the HoloGraph sample app)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="red">#FFFF0000</color>
  <color name="blue">#FF0000FF</color>
  <color name="transparent_blue">#800000FF</color>
  <color name="green">#FF00FF00</color>
  <color name="green_light">#FF99CC00</color>
  <color name="orange">#FFFFBB33</color>
  <color name="transparent_orange">#80FFBB33</color>
  <color name="purple">#FFAA66CC</color>
</resources>
```

Here's how it looks

[image: HoloGraph sample]

Comment: I am going to try and mess with your code a little bit.  I will get back to you.

Comment: Couple of questions.  1) setRange(0, 10);  What is the purpose of this function?  Can you update your answer to have an edittext for the Y value?  I think that will solve my question.

Comment: setRangeY sets the graph range for the Y axis. I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: Answer edited, now takes y coordinate from EditText. (Exceptions not handled - for example you need to handle the case when the EditText is empty or contains invalid stuff)

Comment: @EugeneH I'm happy to hear that, consider assigning the bounty ;)